# Angular 12 - Showing TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'peersContainer') for Html Element

Tags: angular, typescript, 100mslive

#### videocall.html

```
<form id="join" onsubmit="fun()">
    <h2>Join Room</h2>
    <div class="input-container">
        <input id="name" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your name" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-container">
        <input id="token" type="text" name="token" placeholder="Auth token" />
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="join-btn" (click)="fun()">Join</button>
</form>
<div id="conference" class="conference-section">
    <h2>Conference</h2>

    <div #peersContainer id="peersContainer">Nobody in the Room</div>
</div>
```

#### videocall.ts

```
import {
  HMSReactiveStore,
  selectPeers
} from "@100mslive/hms-video-store";

const hms = new HMSReactiveStore();
//hms.triggerOnSubscribe();
const hmsStore = hms.getStore();
const hmsActions = hms.getHMSActions();
@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-call-room',
  templateUrl: './video-call-room.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-call-room.component.css']
})
export class VideoCallRoomComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
  peers = hmsStore.getState(selectPeers);
  constructor() {
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    //window.onunload = this.leaveRoom;
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.peers = hmsStore.getState(selectPeers);
    hmsStore.subscribe(this.renderPeers, selectPeers);
    
  }
  fun() : any{
    console.log("clicked");
    hmsActions.join({
      userName: "nikita",
      authToken: "mytoken"
    });
    console.log("joined");
  }
  leaveRoom() {
    hmsActions.leave();
  }
  @ViewChild("peersContainer",{ static: false }) peersContainer!: ElementRef<any>;
// helper function to create html elements
  h(tag:any, attrs:any, ...children:any[]) {
    const newElement = document.createElement(tag);

    Object.keys(attrs).forEach((key) => {
      newElement.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
    });
    children.forEach((child) => {
      newElement.append(child);
    });
    return newElement;
  }
  renderPeers(peers:any[]) {
    
      // 1. clear the peersContainer
    if (!peers) {
      peers = hmsStore.getState(selectPeers);
    }
    
    this.peersContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML="";
    // 2. loop through the peers and render a tile for each peer
    peers.forEach((peer) => {
      const video = this.h("video", {
        class: "peer-video",
        autoplay: true,
        muted: true,
        playsinline: true,
      });

      hmsActions.attachVideo(peer.videoTrack, video);

      const peerContainer = this.h(
        "div",
        {
          class: "peer-container"
        },
        video,
        this.h(
          "div",
          {
            class: "peer-name"
          },
          peer.name
        )
      );
     this.peersContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(peerContainer);     
    });
  }    //end of renderPeers()

}
```

It's creating session and user is able to join(It's showing in dashboard and camera is getting on). But, it's not able to add html in peersContainer div. Tried to use render2 as well. But same error persists.
Resource - https://docs.100ms.live/javascript/v2/guides/javascript-quickstart

---

Comment: is this `this.peersContainer.nativeElement.innerHTML="";` line show the error?

Comment: @AlanYu yes this line.

Comment: Replace `hmsStore.subscribe(this.renderPeers, selectPeers);` with `hmsStore.subscribe(this.renderPeers.bind(this), selectPeers);` notice `.bind(this)`

Comment: @AlanYu Yeah it worked. It's appending the contents to peersComponent but showing "typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'videoTrack')" in console. Are you able to see any other issue?

Answer (score -2):

You are accesing *peersContainer* through ngAfterViewInit, so that is fine...

I don't know if is going to be this, but... **Could you try to move *peersContainer* just before the constructor?**

Something like:

```
...
export class VideoCallRoomComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild("peersContainer",{ static: false }) peersContainer!: ElementRef<any>;
  peers = hmsStore.getState(selectPeers);

  constructor() {
  }
...
```

If that didn't work, try changing it in theses 2 ways as well:

A)

```
@ViewChild("peersContainer",{ static: true}) peersContainer!: ElementRef<any>;
```

B)

```
@ViewChild('peersContainer') peersContainer!: ElementRef<any>;
```